# how to update the max 10 values in SQL

Tags: sql

I want to update the maximum 10 value by add one to each of those max value. But I don't know how to write the SQL query.

I try my way to create a new table which contains 10 maximum value, and then do the following query below, but got one error: column total can't be null.

```
update familyone
set familyone.total = 
     (select totalmax.total-1 
      from totalmax
      inner join (select * from familyone) as t on t.familyone_id2 = totalmax.familyone_id2
      where familyone.familyone_id2 = totalmax.familyone_id2)
```

Can someone point out my error or think of another way to solve it?

Comment: Please specify which version of SQL. Thx

Answer (score 1):

```
;with a as
(
  select top 10 total 
  from familyone
  order by total desc
)
update a 
set total +=1
```